# Why is the range of usable wifi different to its broadcast range?

Tags: wireless-networking

When lying in my bed (the opposite side of the house to my WAP) I can use the wifi connection. However if the connection drops (which it does every few hours) I can't reconnect instead I have to get up walk towards the AP until the network comes back in range.

Why is it that the wireless network is usable for a slightly bigger range than what I can connect at? Surely if I can use the connection I should be able to connect?

(also this only happens with my phone and iPad, but not my laptop?)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're using to connect has a set minimum connection rate. Once you've made a connection, it'll basically hang on until a timeout or deauth.

With laptops (typically) you have two flat panels as antennas behind the LCD. Usually larger antennas then your phone or tablet, so it has stronger connections. That kind of hints that it's just low signal strength causing the problem if only your phone and tablet are being affected.

Simple solution, move the AP higher. A few feet can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is most certainly an interference issue.  Without knowing your choice of encryption, I would try these things:

1. Depending on your AP, I recommend disabling the 40MHz in the 2.4GHz
   settings on the Wi-Fi router. Mac computers, iPhone, iPad, and iPod
   touch do not support this mode. Disabling it may reduce interference
   issues.
2. Change channels: use one of the free apps to measure –bB signal
   strength. Pick the channel that has the best signal. (a lower number
   is better as it is measured in -dB so higher means a weaker signal)